# Problems on argparse in optional arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

Simple but question that bother me a long time. I have the following command line situation to deal with:

```
program.py
program.py foo
program.py anyotherstring
```

These are the 3 situations I have to deal with in the command line, and I would use them as bool in the if statement following below. The first one is only the program itself, the second situation the following string has to be 'foo' exactly, and the third one 'anyotherstring' just mean any other strings except 'foo'. I got confused be the documentation of argparse and cannot figure out a way to implement it. Could anyone give a solution for that?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: What confuses you about the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) and wouldn't using [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) be sufficient, anyway?

Comment: there is no if statement below

Comment: @StidZhang from theoretical point of view is the question very legitimate, but from ergonomical point of view it is poorly designed command line UI. I would recommend using three subcommands `program.py base`, `program.py foo` and `program.py procstring <somestring>` as it provides much more predictable behaviour.

Comment: Would you be happy with `--foo`?

Comment: Thank all of you guys! I cannot use sys.argv and something that you guys said since I'm modifying some old code and cannot change the basic frame of the code; but still thank all you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try sompething like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="-h for full usage")
parser.add_argument('query', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.query:
    print 'no arguments'
elif args.query == 'foo':
    print 'foo argument'
else:
    print 'random string'
```

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `argparse` you may try `docopt`:

```
"""optargs - testing optional arguments
Usage:
    optargs
    optargs foo
    optargs <somestring>
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print args
```

One can ask for help:

```
$ python optargs.py -h
optargs - testing optional arguments
Usage:
    optargs
    optargs foo
    optargs <somestring>
```

Then, calling it without any argument:

```
$ python optargs.py
{'<somestring>': None,
 'foo': False}
```

then with argument `foo` (you get `"foo"` key set to `True`):

```
$ python optargs.py foo
{'<somestring>': None,
 'foo': True}
```

and finally using arbitrary string (you get `"<somestring>"` key set to `"somstring"`:

```
$ python optargs.py somstring
{'<somestring>': 'somstring',
 'foo': False}
```

Comment: Thanks answering! Although cannot use in my code but quite useful!